# Have not been able to launch Visual Studio Code Insider

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've tried to update the VS Code Insider recently. I don't recall whether the update was complete or not. Ever since then, every time I try to launch VS Code Insider, I get the error "A JavaScript error occurred in the main process." I've kept the screenshot below. [image]

How can this be resolved?

Comment: If you're not sure if the install completed, would it be worth a reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

Likely fixable by a reinstall or fixed by the next insiders build

Please file these sort of issues against VSCode directly in the future: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new